# ExifInterface JHEAD cant open error (android)

Tags: android, image, metadata, exif

I am trying to pick and image from the gallery and print it's path along with the gps tags using ExifInterface. I am using a nexus 4 (kitkat 4.4.2) to debug and the image path I get is

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/image_file_name
>   but the ExifInterface returns null for all tags and the logcat shows an error JHEAD cant open '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/image_file_name' (the app does not crash).
>   Please help.

The main activity code:

```
package com.example.images;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;



import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Intent intent = new     Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);

            }   
     });    


}

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
            Toast.makeText(rl.getContext(), uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            iv.setImageURI(uri);
            String s = getPath(uri);
            TextView tv= new TextView(rl.getContext());
            //System.out.println(s);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView1);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            rl.addView(tv);
            tv.setText(s);
            tv.setId(1);
            //File f= new File(s);
            //Toast.makeText(rl.getContext(), f.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(s);

                String myAttribute="Exif information ---\n";
                 myAttribute += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, exif);
                 myAttribute += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, exif);
                 myAttribute += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, exif);
                 myAttribute += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, exif);
                 float[] output = null;
                Boolean x= exif.getLatLong(output);
                System.out.print(x);
                 TextView tv1= new TextView(rl.getContext());
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView1);
                    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);
                    tv1.setLayoutParams(params1);
                    rl.addView(tv1);
                    tv1.setText(myAttribute);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }
 }
 private String getTagString(String tag, ExifInterface exif)
    {
     return(tag + " : " + exif.getAttribute(tag) + "\n");
    }
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getString(column_index) != null)
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
            else return uri.getPath();
        }
        else return uri.getPath();
    }

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The logcat:

```
02-18 19:59:04.267: D/dalvikvm(9815): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-18 19:59:04.287: D/dalvikvm(9815): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1    entries

02-18 19:59:04.538: D/OpenGLRenderer(9815): Enabling debug mode 0
02-18 19:59:11.905: D/dalvikvm(9815): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 2% free 9147K/9280K,   paused 15ms, total 16ms
02-18 19:59:11.946: I/dalvikvm-heap(9815): Grow heap (frag case) to 39.442MB for 31961104-byte allocation
02-18 19:59:11.956: D/dalvikvm(9815): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 1% free 40356K/40496K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
02-18 19:59:12.306: E/JHEAD(9815): can't open '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140217_210408.jpg'
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.images"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.images.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Okay i solved this by granting  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE". turns out only nexus devices need this permission(app works fine on other phones without this permission). The logcat wasnt clear in mentioning this.